# Trying to send bundle argument

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I'm coding in kotlin on Android Studio. Upon the click of a button, I want to be able to pass arguments through a bundle from my current fragment to the next fragment, and at the same time navigate to the next fragment.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

using Navigation component and that's what you have to write :

```
 val bundle = bundleOf(
                    "title" to "name")

                navController!!.navigate(
                    R.id.action_Fragment1_to_Fragment2,
                    bundle
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jetpack library for android called Navigation graph, that handles such issues like passing data between fragments and similar stuff, along with other features u can search

Initially you need to create a navigation graph, that contains all the fragment with connected graph as per your application logic.

For passing data between fragment, you need to create a argument in navigation action and from there you can send/receive your data easily,

for more information and detail steps refer the links.

Navigation graph : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DI0NIk-7cz8

Navigation safe args : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx1-V3HH0IU